# C-c C-c does not work anymore to compile a tex under Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, keyboard-shortcuts, pdflatex

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.

When I edited `.tex` file under 12.04, I have set up my Emacs in such a way that `C-c C-c` launched automatically `Latex`, `View` or `BibTex` according to the circumstance. Consequently, I just needed to keep pressing `C-c C-c` to compile and view a simple `.tex` file. A part of the `~/.emacs` file is as follows:

```
(require 'server)
(or (server-running-p)
    (server-start))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode) 

(defun pdf-with-okular ()
  (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
           (quote ("^pdf$" "." "okular %o %(outpage)"))))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'pdf-with-okular t)

(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular %o"))) 
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular") (output-dvi "Okular")))

(eval-after-load "tex" 
   '(setcdr (assoc "LaTeX" TeX-command-list)
   '("%`%l%(mode) -shell-escape%' %t"
     TeX-run-TeX nil (latex-mode doctex-mode) :help "Run LaTeX")))

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
```

After upgrading, this mechanism does not work anymore: `C-c C-c` launches `Command [pdflatex]`, and if I just press `Enter`, it could not find the `.tex` file.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command that you describe comes from the AUCTeX extension, which replaces the built-in LaTeX mode of Emacs.  It appears that AUCTeX was not properly upgraded or removed from your system, so you are back to the built-in mode, which is pretty primitive compared to AUCTeX.

Check whether AUCTeX is still available in your Emacs session (e.g. `M-x locate-library RET auctex`).  Also, check whether the [AUCTeX](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/auctex) package is still installed, and reinstall it if necessary.

Alternatively, you can obtain AUCTeX from GNU ELPA with Emacs' built-in package manager, which makes your Emacs setup independent from your system.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the command you expect to be bound to `C-c C-c` is not -- some other command is.

`C-h m` tells you what mode you are in, and some things about it. `C-h k C-c C-c` tells you what command is bound to `C-c C-c`, and it gives you a link to the library where that command is defined.

This info, together with your init file and the Lisp source code, will help you find out why `C-c C-c` is not bound to the command you expect.

And you might want to start your search by bisecting your init file, to narrow it down to the code that causes the problem.

In sum, the answer is to ask Emacs first.